# retrive username and domain with GetUserNameExA

Tags: c++, windows-api-code-pack

I am trying to get username and domain with GetUserNameExA function

this is my code

```
 #include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <Security.h>
#include <secext.h>


DWORD main()
{
    
        CHAR  *username = [200];
        DWORD dwSize = 199;
        memset(username, 0x00, 200);
        GetUserNameExA(NameSamCompatible, username, &dwSize);
        wcout << L"Hello, " << NameSamCompatible << L"!\n";
    

}
```

but keep getting an error that you need to declare an identifer

can you plz help me to figure it out?

Comment: What exact error do you keep getting?

Comment: First time in C++? I recommend [getting a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to help out. C++ rarely rewards guesswork and is not overly forgiving.

Comment: Just FYI, the buffer size you pass into `GetUserNameEx()` needs to include space for the null terminator, so you should be setting `dwSize` to 200, not 199.  Otherwise, just set `dwSize` to 0 instead and let `GetUserNameEx()` tell you the necessary buffer size.

Comment: We'll take the love, but note that [Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CHAR  *username = [200];
```

should be this

```
char username[200];
```

And this

```
wcout << L"Hello, " << NameSamCompatible << L"!\n";
```

should be this

```
cout << "Hello, " << username << "!\n";
```

Comment: Thank you john! much appreciated it! Really trying to improve my coding skills. make some changes and now getting only one error which is ```LNK2001 unresolved external symbol GetUserNameExA``` any idea how to fix this

Comment: @Chantal87  Read the documentation [GetUserNameExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/secext/nf-secext-getusernameexa) __Requirements__ Library: `Secur32.lib`

Comment: Thank you all! I do not know how to say thank you! learned so much! and it is working :)